# Variable number of inputs - Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Need a refresher. I'm sure I know this already but I'm wracking my mind for a more efficient way to do this:

In short, the user is asked how many inputs they'd like to input (up to a certain maximum). For example, let's say they say 10.
Next, they're asked to input a number of single-digit integers equal to the number of inputs they wanted to input (in this case, they'd put in 10 different single-digit integers).

My issue is that I haven't coded Java in a while so I'm rusty. My immediate thoughts go to two options:

1. int input1 = 0, input 2=0, input3=0 ... inputN=0;
2. use an array

While option 1 is incredibly sophomoric it gets the job done. I'm just unsure if there's a simpler way to do it without using arrays.

````
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Histogram
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //variables
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numInputs = 0;
        boolean success = false;


        //start of program
        System.out.println("How many input values [max:20]?");

        while (!success)
        {
            try
            {
                numInputs = keyboard.nextInt();
                numInputChecker(numInputs);
                success = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Single-digit integers only, please.");

            }
        }
        System.out.println("Enter " + numInputs + " numbers.");
       for(int i = 0; i < numInputs; i++)
        {
            // ?????????
        }
    }

    static void numInputChecker(int integer) throws Exception
    {
        if ((integer < 1) || (integer > 20))
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    static void numberChecker(int integer) throws Exception
    {
        if ((integer < 0) || (integer >= 10))
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

}```
````

Comment: An array or `ArrayList` seems fine here. Having individual variables when you don't know ahead of time how many you'll need wouldn't be feasible anyways. I'd just create an `ArrayList` and `add` to it.

Answer (score 0):

i) If you're using multiple values, you're either going to need multiple variables or a collection of some sort. Agree with previous comments on choice of collection. (ii) If the amount of repetition required is counter controlled, why not set the loop to iterate that number of times? You would then need to nest while loops to ensure that your exception handling works but then you could limit the number of inputs. (iii) keyboard.nextInt() may be problematic because nextInt() does not discard the '\n'. It's better to Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine()). (iv) If you're willing to work with strings, then you can do I/O once only and use the split() and Integer.parseInt() methods to get the necessary values.